# Cant run curl command from java code in Linux OS

Tags: java, curl

i have this curl

```
String curlStr = "curl 'http://somesite/env=dev'";
```

when i run this command in cmd it works but it doesnt work from java code
This is what i tried

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(curlStr);
```

Comment: `but it doesnt work` is not exact problem statement.

Comment: Why would you use command line curl from a Java application to begin with? If you need to issue an HTTP request and receive the response, Java has a perfectly capable `HttpClient`.

Comment: This has been answered many times.  Quotation marks are only special to a shell, and Runtime.exec is not a shell.  Seva is right;  use Java to load a URL, not an external `curl` command.

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember exactly the reason but this works :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/sh -c " + curlStr);
```